# Sign SAML Response in Python

Tags: python-3.x, saml-2.0, onelogin

I would need to sign a SAML assertion as it's possible to do on this page :
https://www.samltool.com/sign_response.php

From my side, I'm using Python, and my SAML is in a string.

What would you advise ?

Best regards,

Nico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally made it using [signxml](https://signxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lib.

Just to remind, I wanted to sign the SAML assertion.

I get the unsigned SAML from a file. Then I place this tag <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="placeholder"></ds:Signature> between Issuer tag and Subject tag, as it's recommended by signxml lib. And finally, I sign my SAML and verify the signature. Note that I changed the c14n_algorithm to be compatible with my services.

Here's the code :

```
import re
from lxml import etree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier

with open('saml_to_sign.xml', 'r') as file :
    data_to_sign = file.read()
with open("/vagrant/my_cert.crt", "r") as cert,\
        open("/vagrant/my_key.key", "r") as key:
    certificate = cert.read()
    private_key = key.read()

p = re.search('<Subject>', data_to_sign).start()
tmp_message = data_to_sign[:p]
tmp_message = tmp_message +\
              '<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="placeholder"></ds:Signature>'
data_to_sign = tmp_message + data_to_sign[p:]
print(data_to_sign)

saml_root = etree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_saml_root = XMLSigner(c14n_algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#")\
    .sign(saml_root, key=private_key, cert=certificate)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_saml_root, x509_cert=certificate).signed_xml
signed_saml_root_str = etree.tostring(signed_saml_root, encoding='unicode')
print(signed_saml_root_str)
```